# I suspect this is malware. How do I remove it?

Tags: security

Several pop-ups have recently begun appearing on my MacBook screen.  They coincide with my attempting to update Adobe Flash Player.  I suspect I was careless.  I have never seen pop-ups constantly appearing on my Mac before.  They have no name, so I cannot easily search for where the program is residing and get rid of it. Does anyone recognize these who would be able to instruct me on how to locate and eradicate?

[image: Malware Pop-up]
[image: Malware Pop-up]

Comment: Have you installed Flash from another website because you might get viruses because of that.Try uninstalling the app.

Comment: Great images. Let’s get all the [malware removal general advice in the linked post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252021/suspected-adware-infection-of-mac). If this needs to be edited to explain a specific removal procedure that fails for this specific nasty - we can release the hold and open to new answers.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the Mac, then power it up holding down the shift key. depending on what has infected you that **may** either disable it or reduce its effect on the system.

Download Malwarebytes (or another) virus scanning app for the mac and run it. Hopefully it will be found and removed. If not perhaps someone here recognizes it and knows how to remove it manually.

Alternatively if you have another Mac and the right cables to connect them together you could boot the affected Mac into target disk mode, and plug it into your other Mac that you have installed AV software on and scan the infected drive from there.

Note that these are preliminary steps. other people may have more and/or better suggestions. Proceed with caution and, if possible, turn off the network on the infected Mac.